# 500 Internal server error on apache tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, war, tomcat8

i have a `war` file and i deployed it on my first server. every thing is okay there.
you can test it on http://185.126.201.83:10808/crmapi/rest/v1/authentication/hi
(port is different because it is behind a firewall)
but in my new server i get below error and everything are same in both server. what is wrong?
you can test it on : http://185.21.76.71:8080/crmapi/rest/v1/authentication/hi

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet com.crmapi.services.ApplicationConfig threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.crmapi.services.ApplicationConfig threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:309)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 logs.
```

ubuntu 16.04 Server x64
and Apache Tomcat/8.0.36

Comment: do you have any duplicate resources (jar files) for the same API, like 2 jar files for Jersey with different versions in the classpath ?

Comment: @Yazan How can i check it?

Comment: check your classpath, for a web app mainly it will be `WEB-INF/lib` inside your webapp , or tomcat's `lib` folder, make sure there is not duplicate jar files like `jersey1.0.jar` and `jersey2.0.jar` (for example)

Comment: @Yazan no.... there is no duplicate
and the question is why first server worked correctly but the second has problem?

Comment: sorry i have no idea other than this

Comment: Tell me one thing are you using maven to build your project ?

Comment: I have same error like your issue. Have you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Tomcat stack trace tells it all .Your issue is definitely having multiple JAX-RS jars in the classpath of your application. It looks like javax.ws.rs.core.Application class is loaded from some Jar but it doesn't have the getProperties() method that returns a Java.util.Map . You need to strictly check presence of duplicate jars .If you are not able to find it manually , you can use a tool like JHade to detect presence of duplicate jars .But if you are too sure that application class path has only one JAX-RS jar , please inspect carefully whether it has the required getProperties() method or not in the javax.ws.rs.core.Application class. If you debug your code on these lines, you may end up with a solution. Let me know if that helps you :) . PS - JAX RS 1.x jars do not have getProperties() method but JAX-RS 2.x have .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have jar mismatch of JAX-RS versions.
Use maven to control your JAX-RS version.
If you are using jersey, use 2.23.2 or more versions.

You can check your successful deployment via http://185.21.76.71:8080/crmapi/application.wadl

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the JRE versions differ on your servers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the other error that we are possibly do that we are not declaring our `servlet` class as `public` 
This thing we need to remember because `servlet` container always looks for `servlet` class in public area so our `servlet` file must be public 
Otherwise we will get
Error 500- internal server error.